# Turn numbers to parameters in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to turn the numbers in a sympy expression into parameters. I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import sympy

from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x,y
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import Symbol, lambdify, N

def sympy_param(math_expr):
    param_dict = {}
    unsnapped_param_dict = {'p':1}

    def unsnap_recur(expr, param_dict, unsnapped_param_dict):
        """Recursively transform each numerical value into a learnable parameter."""
        import sympy
        from sympy import Symbol
        if isinstance(expr, sympy.numbers.Float) or isinstance(expr, sympy.numbers.Integer) or isinstance(expr, sympy.numbers.Rational) or isinstance(expr, sympy.numbers.Pi):
            used_param_names = list(param_dict.keys()) + list(unsnapped_param_dict)
            unsnapped_param_name = get_next_available_key(used_param_names, "p", is_underscore=False)
            unsnapped_param_dict[unsnapped_param_name] = float(expr)
            unsnapped_expr = Symbol(unsnapped_param_name)
            return unsnapped_expr
        elif isinstance(expr, sympy.symbol.Symbol):
            return expr
        else:
            unsnapped_sub_expr_list = []
            for sub_expr in expr.args:
                unsnapped_sub_expr = unsnap_recur(sub_expr, param_dict, unsnapped_param_dict)
                unsnapped_sub_expr_list.append(unsnapped_sub_expr)
            return expr.func(*unsnapped_sub_expr_list)

    def get_next_available_key(iterable, key, midfix="", suffix="", is_underscore=True):
        """Get the next available key that does not collide with the keys in the dictionary."""
        if key + suffix not in iterable:
            return key + suffix
        else:
            i = 0
            underscore = "_" if is_underscore else ""
            while "{}{}{}{}{}".format(key, underscore, midfix, i, suffix) in iterable:
                i += 1
            new_key = "{}{}{}{}{}".format(key, underscore, midfix, i, suffix)
            return new_key

    eq = parse_expr(math_expr)
    eq = unsnap_recur(eq,param_dict,unsnapped_param_dict)
    return eq
```

It works well on most cases. For example, if I run:

```
math_expr = "3.1+exp(1.1*x0)-0.3*log(x1**7)"
print(sympy_param(math_expr))
```

I get as output:

```
p0 + p1*log(x1**p2) + exp(p3*x0)
```

which is what I need. However when I try:

```
math_expr = "-5.4-1.6/x0"
print(sympy_param(math_expr))
```

I get this:

```
p0 + p1*x0**p2
```

It is not wrong technically, but that power kinda messes up my overall code (for the next step after this). Is there a way to prevent that p2 in the power to appear there (that is not really an explicit number appearing in my equation), so ideally I would like to get:

```
p0 + p1/x0
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: You could check for `Pow` and if then if `isinstance(expr.exp, Rational)` don't replace the exponent with a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SymPy represents `1/x` as `Pow(x, -1)`. You may also run into a similar issue with something like `x - y`, which SymPy represents as `Add(x, Mul(-1, y))`. The best way to avoid this issue is to check for those cases specifically (like `isinstance(expr, Pow) and expr.exp == -1`).